# Creating an adding and subtracting formula in Numbers

Tags: macos, ms-office, numbers

I'm creating a financial spreadsheet and need to ask the spreadsheet to calculate the new balance after subtracting and adding sums. For example, I want to calculate the running total in E column. I have an amount in E3. The spreadsheet will need to subtract the amount in C4 and add the amount in D4 to achieve the current amount.

Everytime I've tried to do this I've received an error message.

Comment: Which error message do you get? Which formula did you use? Adding a screenshot of your sheet showing the relevant fields would help as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess: Try entering the formula without the = sign.

This sounds like the most irritating problem I had with Numbers: When you enter a formula, often it 'helps' by reformatting the = sign you entered into a pretty icon for an equals sign. Which I looked at and said "This is where my formula goes", so I entered "=E3-C4+D4" (or whatever your equation should be).

The problem is, now there are two (==) equals signs (because the iconic one really counted as part of the equation), and it gave me an obscure formula error. Took me 30 minutes to figure out what was going on.